# Mapping a list of label with one hot encoding

Tags: python, list, deep-learning, pytorch, one-hot-encoding

How can I do the same thing when 'label' is a list?
For example: label = [2,4,6,1,7...,9]

```
label = 3
NumClass = 10
NumRows  = 100

mask    =  torch.zeros(100, 64)
ones     =  torch.ones(1, 64)
ElementsPerClass = NumRows//NumClass
mask [ ElementsPerClass*label : ElementsPerClass*(label+1) ] = ones
```

Comment: what is your expected output when label is `list`?

Comment: @DishinHGoyani The expected output is the same as the above matrix, but above works for batch_size = 1. I want it to work for batch_size = 16,32,.. In that case, there will be a row vector of the above matrix.

What's happening here is, 100 is the memory dimension. and there are 10 classes so each class will get a slot of 10 in the memory. In my code above if you have a label value it reserves those 10 slots for that corresponding label. I want to do this for a batch of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_):

```py
NumRows = len(label)
mask = torch.zeros((NumRoes, NumClass)).scatter_(dim=1, index=torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.long)[:, None], src=torch.ones(NumRows, 1))
```

Comment: It doesn't produce the result I want!
The expected output is the same as the above matrix, but above works for batch_size = 1. I want it for batch of input (16,32,..) In that case, there will be a row vector of the above matrix. What's happening here is, 100 is the memory dimension. and there are 10 classes so each class will get a slot of 10 in the memory. In my code above if you have a label value it reserves those 10 slots for that corresponding label. I want to do this for a batch of input.